# A simple database and Query System?

Tags: database-design, performance, query-performance

I am new to databases and trying to solve one problem in which I have to build a simple database having few entries and then querying that database and then recording that answers from the database. I have to send many queries one by one. It is kind of experiment to learn database.
Could anyone suggest which simple software or language can I use to do that. I would prefer some high-level language. I know that it is doable in C/C++ but it does look fun in doing C/C++.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using Postgres as the database for a beginner. This is the most ANSI compliant one of the open source databases. Unlike MySQL, it wont teach you any bad habits.

Pretty much all languages support querying Postgres, MySQL and SQL Server - just pick the languages you want to learn.

Comment: Is there any sample program written in C/C++ to query the database?

Comment: SQL Server contains C/C++ samples that you can pick as part of the installers. Google for MySQL and Postgres, plenty of examples

Answer (score 1):

The simplest - shell script running psql commands :)  Otherwise, any high-level language can be used for the sake of experiment to learn database - ruby, python, java, etc.